# D3.js .rangeBands() returning 'undefined' with only the last value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

New to D3.js and trying to create a bar graph with 275 sets of values. I used an ordinal scale to position the bars along the x-axis and the last value returns "undefined" and therefore is positioned all the way to the left. I can't figure out why, or how to fix it...

Here's a gist of what I have: https://gist.github.com/shawnparrotte/2e17c4914771f3ea5fe6

The function between lines 81-84 is where it goes down, specifically at line 83:

```
   bands.range()[i]
```

Thanks for taking a look at this!

** Edit: It seems like the ordinal scale only returned 274 values even though I sent it an array of 275 values... see lines 70-73. Strange.

Comment: You can just multiply the band width by `i` here, can't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain( [0, maxGDP] )
                         .range( [0, gHeight] );
```

It means your y axis is based on gdp.

But when you do:

```
          // ordinal scale for the bar width
        var bands = d3.scale.ordinal()
                            .domain(gdp)//this is strange! should be dates
                            .rangeBands( [0, gWidth], .2);
```

It means your x axis is linked to GDP which is strange!

It should have been linked to the date.

```
         // ordinal scale for the bar width
        var bands = d3.scale.ordinal()
                            .domain(dates)
                            .rangeBands( [0, gWidth], .2);
```

This will fix your issue.

**Lastly**:

Why do you see 274 rangebands when you do have 275!

```
var bands = d3.scale.ordinal()
                                .domain(gdp)
                                .rangeBands( [0, gWidth], .2);
```

**reason** there are 2 gdp which is same and scale ordinal will always give unique rangebands thus for 275 gdp you get 274 after getting unique.

However you should consider x domain as dates.

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NScBeNWvlOsBIkIvlEkC?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Cyril. I'm an idiot... the x-axis _is_ supposed to be the dates. It was staring me in the face the whole time! You're a lifesaver!